# How to pool hazard ratios from multi-arm study to get a unique HR between two arms?

Tags: meta-analysis, pooling

Good morning

I should start a meta-analysis but I am facing with a problem of extracting/combining data from one study.
I am comparing A versus B population in terms of overall survival. The study reports HRs of subgroups of my populations, that could be easily split, reporting the subgroup HRs having as reference one of the subgroups.

E.g.
Group A is reported as A1 and A2;
Group B is reported as B1 and B2.
The study reports HRs (95%CI) of A1, A2, B1 having as reference B2.

Is there any method I can use to combine these HRs in order for me to have only the HR (and 95%CI) of the comparison A vs B?

Hope to have been clear.

Thank you very much

Fabio